# Did God command Hazael to tell a lie to Ben-Hadad in 2 Kings 8:10?

Tags: 2-kings

> 2 Kings 8:9 Hazael went to meet Elisha, taking with him as a gift forty camel-loads of all the finest wares of Damascus. He went in and stood before him, and said, “Your son Ben-Hadad king of Aram has sent me to ask, ‘Will I recover from this illness?’ ”
>
> 10 Elisha answered, “Go and say to him, ‘You will certainly recover.’ Nevertheless, the Lord has revealed to me that he will in fact die.”

Is lying a sin?

Did God command Hazael to mislead Ben-Hadad in 2 Kings 8:10?

Comment: _Thou mayest certainly recover: howbeit the LORD hath shewed me that he shall surely die._ [KJV] _Thou dost certainly not revive, seeing Jehovah hath shewed me that he doth surely die.'_ [Young's Literal]. KJV and YLT translate differently but neither contains a lie.('Thou mayest recover' does not promise anything.)

Comment: @Ba's answer here I think should solve your problem https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/40146/did-elisha-tell-hazael-that-ben-hadad-will-recover-in-2-kings-8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did Elisha tell Hazael that Ben Hadad will recover in 2 Kings 8?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/40146/did-elisha-tell-hazael-that-ben-hadad-will-recover-in-2-kings-8)

Comment: @NigelJ that's the question I linked in my comment, however I wouldn't go so far as to say that it's an exact duplicate of that one. It's definitely related and the answer over there may even resolve the OP's question, but we have to be careful when we close a question in the name of it being a duplicate.

Comment: @Bach The answer to the previous question obviates the necessity of asking this question. In my opinion.

Comment: @NigelJ that's true, but to me it still doesn't justify marking it as duplicate since they are two very different questions. The fact that an answer to an unrelated question also resolves another question does not entail that the the questions are duplicates of each other. Keep in mind that questions are marked as duplicate, not answers.

Comment: The question is “will he recover?” The answer is “yes”. If he had followed up with the question “will you kill me in the process” and he answered “no” but then kills him then that’s lying otherwise he answered the question with respect to his recovery. Where is the hang up? I think it’s the English language because what he is asking is not so much WILL I recover but CAN I recover. And the answer is yes it’s possible to recover. It’s ambiguous in the original but inferred is if he can, he also will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We often underestimate the levels of sarcasm and innuendo present in the Bible writers, often falsely attributing to them only simple speech and pious blessings.  Life is and never was that simple.

When Hazael presented himself before the prophet Elisha, he immediately saw through the messenger's murderous intentions and immediately saw how Hazael intended to usurp the throne by deception and regicide.  Elisha knew that Hazael would lie to the king to gain his confidence.

Thus, Elisha said to Hazael something like, "Say to Ben Hadad, You will certainly recover because that is what you will say to him no matter what I say.  However, the king will die, not from this disease but by your hand."

If Hazael had reported Elisha's words to the king in full, no lie would have been told.

Commentaries reach a similar conclusion.  Note the Pulpit Commentary on 2 Kings 8:10 -

> What Elisha says to Hazael is, "Go, say unto him, Thou shalt surely
>   live;" i.e. "Go, say unto him, what thou hast already made up thy mind
>   to say, what a courtier is sure to say, Thou shalt recover." Howbeit
>   the Lord hath showed me that he shall surely die. If Hazael had
>   reported the whole answer to Benhadad, he would have told no lie, and
>   thus Elisha is not responsible for his lie.

Ellicott reaches an identical conclusion.

> Thou wilt certainly live. Elisha sees through Hazael's character and
>   designs, and answers him in the tone of irony which he used to Gehazi
>   in 2 Kings 5:26, "Go, tell thy lord--as thou, the supple and
>   unscrupulous courtier wilt be sure to do--he will certainly recover. I
>   know, however, that he will assuredly die, and by thy hand." Others
>   interpret, "Thou mightest recover" (i.e., thy disease is not mortal);
>   and make the rest of the prophet's reply a confidential communication
>   to Hazael. But this is to represent the prophet as deceiving Benhadad,
>   and guilty of complicity with Hazael, which agrees neither with
>   Elisha's character nor with what follows in 2 Kings 8:11-12.

Comment: I'd like to copy your answer here over to my subreddit :)

Comment: @TonyChan - You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

@tony-chan @dottard @collen-ndhlovu I do Not believe Elisha was lying. Let me explain, I've met people with  Pentecostal/Charismatic church background who have the Charismatic gift of discernment/prophesy.
In rare cases, it's really interesting how some of these Discernment/Prophetic Charismatic people/ministers are blessed to reveal Godly information.

As you read through (2 Kings 8:9-12), if you think about it, Elisha is sort of like a sonarman.

1. First bit of Godly information

> (2 Kings 8:10a) (NASB1995)
>
> .....“Go, say to him, ‘You will surely recover,’

2. ..Waits a little, and 2nd bit of Godly information

> (2 Kings 8:10b) (NASB1995)
> .....“......but the Lord has shown me that he will certainly die.”.....

3. ...Some more waiting.... and until the he was ashamed

> (2 Kings 8:11a) NASB1995
> 11 He [d]fixed his gaze steadily on him until he was ashamed,.......
> ........

4. ...Finally... the complete information is revealed....

> (2 Kings 8:11b-12) NASB1995  and the man of God wept. 12 Hazael said,
> “Why does my lord weep?” Then he [e]answered, “Because I know the evil
> that you will do to the sons of Israel: their strongholds you will set
> on fire, and their young men you will kill with the sword, and their
> little ones you will dash in pieces, and their women with child you
> will rip up.”

**It's sort of like a sonar operator/sonarman on a submarine who is carefully listening for important sounds, and as time goes by get a surprised(or sometimes sadly shocking) look on their faces when they receive important bits of Godly information.**